# getting error on export to PDF in fast report

Tags: c#, fastreport

when I open designer and simply bring a textbox then write a few words in it in Kurdish(somehow similar to Arabic characters). when I go to `file-> preview` its okay as in the figure

[image]

but when I go to SAVE and export to PDF I get 15 problems
such as in the figure

[image]

of problem(font table checksum error)

Table ID "cvt" checksum error
Table ID "PCLT" checksum error
Table ID "cmap" checksum error
Table ID "name" checksum error
Table ID "hmtx" checksum error
Table ID "maxp" checksum error
Table ID "cvt" checksum error
Table ID "post" checksum error
Table ID "OS/2" checksum error
Table ID "prep" checksum error
Table ID "head" checksum error
Table ID "fpgm" checksum error
Table ID "hhea" checksum error
Table ID "glyf" checksum error

Comment: here is the links 
  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/fb3QJ.png
  [2]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/MGAjY.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue in Delphi, found this solution:

In `ExportPack\frxTrueTypeCollection.pas`, replace

> ChecksumFaultAction_Warn

with

> ChecksumFaultAction_IgnoreChecksum
> :

Line 124:

```
f := TrueTypeFont.Create( Pointer(FD), Pointer(FD), ChecksumFaultAction_IgnoreChecksum);
```

Line 143:

```
f := TrueTypeFont.Create(FD, subfont_ptr, ChecksumFaultAction_IgnoreChecksum);
```

I guess for C# it should be very similar.

Comment: Dear brother, what do you mean by :
in ExportPack\frxTrueTypeCollection.pas, replace ChecksumFaultAction_Warn with ChecksumFaultAction_IgnoreChecksum:

Comment: I found the file ExportPack\frxTrueTypeCollection.pas in FastReport install dir, c:\Program Files (x86)\FastReports\LibD20 on my machine.

I encountered other problems with Fast Report PDF export filter, so I switched to Synopse PDF engine, but it's for Delphi/Object Pascal only AFAIK.

Anyway If you still have troubles, I would recommend to search/ask on the original FastReport support forum.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem because of using #RowNo in table. I remove this parameter and set row number in table as a column, so error has been removed.

Answer (score -1):

in c# before export to pdf add this command :

```
    FastReport.Export.Pdf.PDFExport pdf = new FastReport.Export.Pdf.PDFExport();
pdf.EmbeddingFonts = false;
 report1.Export(pdf, YourPath + "\\filename.pdf");
```

best regards

Comment: we should embed the fonts, so pdf.EmbeddingFonts is must set to true;